# utf-8 encoding in gemspec, does it apply to the source files?

Tags: ruby, encoding, rubygems

According to the ruby guide we have decided to use which can be found [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#collections) it seems like it's a very good idea to specify the encoding of a gem and the source files within the gem.  My question is does:

`# -- encoding: utf-8 --`

At the top of a gemspec filter through all the files in the gem or should it be specified in each file for completeness?

I would hope it filters throughout the files in the gem but would rather ask and be safe than sorry!!

I also looked at:

[How does the magic comment ( # Encoding: utf-8 ) in ruby​​ work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879237/how-does-the-magic-comment-encoding-utf-8-in-ruby-works)

and

[How can I avoid putting the magic encoding comment on top of every UTF-8 file in Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291017/how-can-i-avoid-putting-the-magic-encoding-comment-on-top-of-every-utf-8-file-in)

According to the later link there is no way to ensure this short of putting it in every file but I wondered whether the gemspec declaration was special in some way??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file encoding header specifies the encoding for that file. It doesn't specify the encoding of other files. How could it?